# Parsing HTTParty response

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api

I'm using HTTParty to pull a list of a Facebook user's books but I'm having trouble parsing the response:

Facebook returns data this way:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Title", 
      "category": "Book", 
      "id": "21192118877902", 
      "created_time": "2011-11-11T20:50:47+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Title 2", 
      "category": "Book", 
      "id": "1886126860176", 
      "created_time": "2011-11-05T02:35:56+0000"
    },
```

And HTTParty parses that into a ruby object. I've tried something like this (where `ret` is the response) `ret.parsed_response` and that returns the data array, but actually accessing the items inside returns a method not found error.

This is a sample of what HTTParty actually returns:

```
#<HTTParty::Response:0x7fd0d378c188 @parsed_response={"data"=>
[{"name"=>"Title", "category"=>"Book", "id"=>"21192111877902", "created_time"=>"2011-11-11T20:50:47+0000"},
 {"name"=>"Title 2", "category"=>"Book", "id"=>"1886126860176", "created_time"=>"2011-11-05T02:35:56+0000"},
 {"name"=>"Thought Patterns", "category"=>"Book", "id"=>"109129539157186", "created_time"=>"2011-10-27T00:00:16+0000"},
```

Comment: Are you trying like this `ret.parsed_response["data"]` and `ret.parsed_response["data"].first["name"]`?

Comment: No ... I was doing `ret.parsed_response.data`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Do you have any code that is throwing an error? The `parsed_response` variable from the HTTParty response is a hash, not an array.  It contains one key, `"data"` (the string, NOT the symbol).  The value for the `"data"` key in the hash is an array of hashes, so you would iterate as such:

```
data = ret.parsed_response["data"]
data.each do |item|
  puts item["name"]
  puts item["category"]
  puts item["id"]
  # etc
end
```

Comment: That was my trouble -- using `data` the way you've done here. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

Just an additional info - **It's Not Always a default JSON response**

HTTParty's `result.response.body` or `result.response.parsed_response` does **not** always have form of a **Hash**

It just depends generally on the headers which you are using in your request. **For e.g.**, you need to specify `Accept` header with `application/json` value while hitting **GitHub API**, otherwise it simply returns as **string**.

Then you shall have to use `JSON.parse(data)` for same to convert the string response into Hash object.