# Rails: Parsing HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I've read other answers on this topic, such as:

[Parsing HTTParty response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8171881/parsing-httparty-response)

[HTTParty parsing JSON in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420913/httparty-parsing-json-in-rails)

However, I still can't figure out how to parse a response I'm receiving.

`response.parsed_response = HTTParty.get(url, query: params)` returns:

`=> #<HTTParty::Response:0x89435d0 parsed_response="http://foo.com", @response=#<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>, @headers={"cache-control"=>["no-cache", "no-store"], "date"=>["Tue, 21 Feb 2017 23:10:47 GMT"], "expires"=>["Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"], "p3p"=>["CP=\"ALL IND DSP COR CUR ADM TAIo PSDo OUR COM INT NAV PUR STA UNI\""], "pragma"=>["no-cache"], "server"=>["Apache-Coyote/1.1"], "set-cookie"=>["bar.Agent.p=c1921b97d1f8a0918621c48bd32ded2b; Domain=.bar.com; Expires=Fri, 19-Feb-2027 23:10:47 GMT; Path=/"], "content-length"=>["366"], "connection"=>["Close"]}>`

I need the URL that appears after `parsed_response`.  The other answers seemed to break down hashes that appear after parsed_response, but I'm just looking for the url that appears after parsed_response (and it only appears there in the response).

I tried: 
`puts response` which returns the entire response above.

`puts response.parsed_response` which returns:

```
http://foo.com
=> nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually works for me

```
response = HTTParty.get(url, options)
puts response.body
```